# Convert time to hour + AM/PM?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just a quick question hopefully. I am using SQL Server 2016.

I have a `datetime` column; what's the best way to create an output from this which looks like 4PM, 12AM etc?

For example.. 2016-01-03 09:14:23 would become 9AM, and 2016-01-03 00:34:43 would be 12AM?

Many thanks for any help!! :)

Comment: Do u want to only extract time string or would u like all datetime in varchar ?ex; `Feb 27 2018  1:56PM`

Answer (score 2):

Use `format()` function available from SQL Server 2012+ to get the time format(AM/PM) only

```
select format(getdate(), 'hh tt')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FORMAT`

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), N'htt')
```